# How can I pull items from database select with session array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, session

I have code that adds an array to a session like this:

```
array_push($_SESSION['cart']['1'] = 3);
array_push($_SESSION['cart']['18'] = 1);
```

This would add item id "1" with quantity "3" and add item id "18" with quantity "1".  I want to show these items from database on cart page. 
I'm not good in php or sql, but something like:

```
while (list ($id, $quantity) = each ($_SESSION['cart'])) { 
$results = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id ASC");
}
```

and do something like find `$id(from session) = $id(from database)` so I could show session as information from database. With item name, item desc., item price, and quantity.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick example highlighting what u're trying to retrieve (id_item) from $_SESSION :

http://www.tehplayground.com/#Iyf7c0LTM

```
$arr = array();
$arr['cart']['1'] = 3;
$arr['cart']['18'] = 5;

// This loop will display every id_item that had be added to the "cart"
foreach($arr['cart'] as $row)
{
    print "id_item : " . $row . "\n";
}
```

U can use now make ur sql query :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id =". $row;
```

**EDIT** - Since it was unclear for you, I made u the direct answer :

```
<?php
session_start();

// Examples of shopped items (added to $_SESSION['cart'])
$_SESSION['cart']['1'] = 3;
$_SESSION['cart']['18'] = 5;

// This loop will display every id_item that had be added to the "cart"
// Further informations how foreach works with array 
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $row)
{
    print "id_item : " . $row . "\n";
}

// Full Display to help understanding the process
print "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
print "</pre>";

?>
```

Advanced explanations about "how foreach interacts with array" : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works)

**EDIT 2 :**
Fill db variables + column names of your table

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

// Query the DB - Get itemID & quantity added in the cart table
$query = "SELECT itemID, itemQuantity FROM cart";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

// Return the result into an array
$res_array = $result->fetch_array();

// Add the items into $_SESSION
// Pattern : $_SESSION['cart']['$itemId'] = $itemQuantity

foreach($res_array as $row)
    $_SESSION['cart'][($row['itemID'])] = $row['itemQuantity']

print "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
print "</pre>";
?>
```

Example : [here](http://www.tehplayground.com/#ob3pMbOFo)

Comment: I tried this way and couldn't get anywhere. You know another way that would work?  Or maybe describe this way better.  You like takes to a page with code that does not do anything.  Thanks.

Comment: Ctrl+enter will display it. It.s a php fiddle

Comment: Ok you aren't understanding my question.  I need to show these items in `$_SESSION` from a database.  Referencing by item id.  I already have a full session and cart system set up.  But it holds information like `array_push($_SESSION['cart']['$itemName'] = $itemPrice);`  I am trying to do `array_push($_SESSION['cart']['$itemId'] = $itemQuantity);`  then compare to database and pull `item1` info from database into cart.  Thanks. God Bless.

Comment: Are u using pdo or mysqli to connect to your db?

Comment: Question was really unclear - Updated one last time with ur needs - See EDIT 2

Answer (score 0):

Rather than getting everything from the database and then comparing in php you can do something like this to only get the records that you need:

```
"SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN(1,18) ORDER BY id ASC"
```

The PHP might be as simple as: `$in = implode(",", $_SESSION['cart']);` although you should also make sure to protect against SQL injection.